# JavaFX: Changing CSS file outside of Main class

Tags: java, css, javafx

There is a question related to this that was already answered but I would like to know how to change the CSS file outside of the main class and inside the controller or perhaps some more appropriate classes.

```
package calc;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private void skinSelector(ActionEvent event) {
        // Where the magic happens!
    }
}
```

Comment: Just the same as always: grab the scene and are whatever stylesheet you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably help you.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhmIC.png)

**main.fxml**

```
<Pane fx:id="rootPane" stylesheets="@theme1.css" styleClass="pane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="200.0" layoutY="200.0" onAction="#press" text="Button" />
     </children>
</Pane>
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
private Pane rootPane;

@FXML
private void press(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        rootPane.getStylesheets().clear();
        rootPane.getStylesheets().add(
                                getClass()
                                .getResource("theme2.css")
                                .toExternalForm()
                            );
    }
}
```

**theme1.css**

```
.pane{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

**theme2.css**

```
.pane{
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: If you want to change the style sheets on the scene, instead of just in the root, then you can replace `rootPane.getStylesheets()` with `rootPane.getScene().getStylesheets()`

Comment: @James_D Most often this doesn't make sense, my Pane is the root panel.

Comment: It depends on the use case, of course, but if you wanted the change to persist after loading a new FXML file into the same scene, for example, you'd want to set the stylesheet on the scene.